# Как поступить с файлом tomcat.xml в Gretty плагине, когда там содержится пароль от СУБД?

Tags: java, tomcat, gretty

Для разработки веб-приложений на Java я использую Gretty  плагин. Я хочу разработать Tomcat приложение и разместить исходный код на github'e, но не понимаю как мне быть с файлом tomcat.xml, в котором настраивается пулл конектов к СУБД. Там ведь лежит пароль от базы. Слышал что-то про переменные окружения, но не знаю можно ли совместить их и конфигурационный файл tomcat'a!? Собственно вопрос: как быть?

Comment: Заменить ваш пароль на YOU_PASSWORD_HERE в tomcat.xml и в readme.md на gihub жЫрным текстом написать, что нуждно прописать пароль к БД(Также можно поступить с url JDBC и Login)

Comment: Второй вариант - действительно использовать переменные окружения. Что-то типа $DATABASE_PASSWORD(если это linux). А в самом скрипте запуска TC или `в .bashrc` добавить `export DATABASE_PASSWORD=passw1234`

Answer (score 0):

Есть чуть более сложный подход с шифрованием 
Пример использования Bouncy castle: https://github.com/cristianprofile/spring-boot-thread-local-and-bouncy-castle